# TYPO3 Scheduler + Symfony Console Command + Command Arguments

Tags: symfony, console, typo3, scheduler

There is a Symfony Console Command which can be executed by CLI with an argument „domain“. Like:

```
./typo3cms mycrawler:process www.domain.ltd
```

All fine so far. When running this command from „Scheduler“ using „Console Command Scheduler Task“, how can the commands argument „domain“ be set from the tasks edit form (backend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the value **Execute console commands**, add also a frequency and press *Save*. After that you can add arguments and options

[image: Options and arguments]

---

the shown HTML is currently a regression, sorry for that - it is known and reported.